# Android WebView.evaluateJavascript() and uncaught reference error

Tags: javascript, android, webview, undefined-reference

I load a web page (main.html) with

`webview.loadUrl("file::///android_asset/main.html");`

main.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script>
    function myTest() {
 document.getElementById("myH").innerHTML = "myTest() worked"
    }
</script>
<html>
<head><title>This is a test</title></head>
<body>    
    <h1 id="myH">This site is under development</h1>
<script>
 //myTest();  this works but I need to run it programatically after page load
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In main.html, a function, myTest(), has been defined and I can invoke it with a script block in main.html:

`<script> myTest(); </script>`

But when I try to run it with evaluateJavascript():

`webview.evaluateJavascript("myTest()", null);`

I get the error message:

> I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: myTest is not defined", source:  (1)

Any idea what went wrong?  I have the impression that others do not have this problem.

Comment: can you please show your code.

Comment: I added HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this achieved what I wanted:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
            view.loadUrl("javascript:myTest()");
        }
```

I suppose that when the first call to loadUrl() returns, the page may not have been fully loaded, so myTest() remains undefined. I am still puzzled about the purpose of evaluateJavascript() since it did not work even under this condition.

Comment: True, I experienced the same error even I did force the evaluateJavascript() run after onPageFinished event. My guess is the page was loaded but the js file not completely finished. Lucky me, I did also have the control of the js file, so I call a function in Android to call the same evaluateJavascript() it made sure the js file was completely loaded.